# On the occurrence of 'two summers' on certain regions of the Earth

Tags: climate, seasons

My conception is that the two factors affecting seasons should be the following:

1. The relative duration of day and night throughout one rotation
2. The angle made by the sunlight w.r.t the normal to the surface.
   I can understand that the Equator will experience two instances of temperature peaks(or two summers, as one may call it,) throughout the revolution of the Earth. This is because the duration of day and night is the same on the Equator throughout, so the angle at which it receives sunlight becomes the controlling factor. During the solstices when the point on the Equator experiences noon it receives sunlight at a certain angle whereas its directly overhead during the Equinoxes. Thus the spike in temperature is explained.
   However this isn't the case for other regions. Northern hemispheres always have a longer daytime during solstices. Yet the region between the Tropic of Cancer and the Equator experiences two peaks of temperature. Please explain what's going on.

Comment: You should probably give some locations... I tried climographs for San Jose CR, Roseau, Dakar, Bangkok, Manila, or nearer Equator sites like Quito, Singapore and none showed a pronounced double peak.  But something that may help your consideration is: what's the situation like a few hundred miles from the Equator?  That can be a start for some spots... and then there's a second key feature that really impacts some areas like India and Sudan that I'd think someone will write a good answer on (if this question hasn't been asked before here?)